# LINQ for 3 tables - new to LINQ

Tags: linq, lambda, entity-framework-6

I have 3 tables

> **Users** - UserID, Firstname, LastName, etc
>
> **Roles** - RoleId, RoleName
>
> **Features** - UserId, RoleId

I want to display Users with common features using LINQ

Please help

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
Also see [ask].

Answer (score 1):

you can try a lookup:

```
//Associate the role names with the features
var featureRoles = dbContext.Roles.Join(dbContext.Features,
                       role => role.RoleId,
                       feature => feature.RoleId,
                       (role, feature) => new {
                                                RoleId = feature.RoleId,
                                                UserId = feature.UserId,
                                                RoleName = role.RoleName
                                               });

//Create ILookup
var lookup = dbContext.Users.Join(featureRoles,
                       user => user.UserID,
                       fr => fr.UserId,
                       (user, fr) => new {
                                           User = user,
                                           RoleName = fr.RoleName,
                                           RoleId = fr.RoleId
                                         })
                      .ToLookup(r => r.RoleName, s => s.User);
```

This will sort your users by their role name for example:

```
var users = lookup["role 1"];
foreach(var user in users)
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("Users in Role 1:");
    Console.WriteLine("\t{0} {1}", user.Firstname, user.Lastname);  
}

Output:
"Users in Role 1:"
         "John Smith"
         "Foo Bar"
         ...
```

If you want to search by the role id in stead of the name then you will need to alter the lookup definition to `.ToLookup(r=> r.RoleId, s=> s.User)`

Answer (score 0):

```
from u in Users
join f in Features on u.UserId equals f.UserId
join r in Roles on r.RoleId equals f.RoleId
where f.RoleId == 1
select new { u.FirstName,u.LastName,r.RoleName}
```

Comment: Thanks for prompt response Tony.I am thinking this would return all Users and their features. I would like to see user and feature if they have common feature, Like user 1 is role 1 and user 2 is role 1. Any help please?